# Use ngMessages with Angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know if there is a fork of Angular 1.2 that supports ngMessages?

I'd love to use this but I have a requirement for IE8.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated pleerock's answer to handle element directives having `for` and `when` attributes like `ngMessages` and `ngMessage`. You can find the same in this [github repo](https://github.com/tilwinjoy/ui-messages)

```js
angular.module('uiMessages', []).directive('uiMessages', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // hide all message elements
      var messageElements = element.find('ui-message,[ui-message]').css('display', 'none');
      // watch when messages object change - change display state of the elements
      scope.$watchCollection(attrs.uiMessages || attrs['for'], function(messages) {
        var oneElementAlreadyShowed = false;
        angular.forEach(messageElements, function(messageElement) {
          messageElement = angular.element(messageElement);
          var message = messageElement.attr('ui-message') || messageElement.attr('when');
          if (!oneElementAlreadyShowed && messages[message] && messages[message] === true) {
            messageElement.css('display', 'block');
            oneElementAlreadyShowed = true;
          } else {
            messageElement.css('display', 'none');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="userForm" ng-app="uiMessages" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" required />
  <ui-messages for="userForm.firstname.$error" ng-show="userForm.firstname.$dirty">
    <ui-message when="required">This field is mandatory</ui-message>
  </ui-messages>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" required />
  <div ui-messages="userForm.lastname.$error" ng-show="userForm.lastname.$dirty">
    <div ui-message="required">This field is mandatory</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks TJ, love it and looks awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Here is my directive I use:

```
/**
 * Ui-messages is similar implementation of ng-messages from angular 1.3
 *
 * @author Umed Khudoiberdiev <info@zar.tj>
 */
angular.module('uiMessages', []).directive('uiMessages', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // hide all message elements
            var messageElements = element[0].querySelectorAll('[ui-message]');
            angular.forEach(messageElements, function(message) {
                message.style.display = 'none';
            });

            // watch when messages object change - change display state of the elements
            scope.$watchCollection(attrs.uiMessages, function(messages) {
                var oneElementAlreadyShowed = false;

                angular.forEach(messageElements, function(message) {
                    var uiMessage = angular.element(message).attr('ui-message');

                    if (!oneElementAlreadyShowed && messages[uiMessage] && messages[uiMessage] === true) {
                        message.style.display = 'block';
                        oneElementAlreadyShowed = true;
                    } else {
                        message.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I've used `ui-messages` instead of `ng-messages` to avoid conflicts.

```
<div ui-messages="form.name.$error">
    <div ui-message="minlength">too short</div>
    <div ui-message="required">this is required</div>
    <div ui-message="pattern">pattern dismatch</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this example really different from a ngSwitch ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know for sure if a fork exists but it would be easy enough to roll your own `ng-message` (or something that serves the same purpose). I think the following would do it:

**Controller**

```
app.controller("Test", function ($scope) {
  $scope.messages = {
    "key1": "Message1",
    "key2": "Message2",
    "key3": "Message3"};

  $scope.getMessage = function (keyVariable) {
    return $scope.messages[keyVariable.toLowerCase()];
  };

  $scope.keyVariable = 'key1';
});
```

**HTML (example)**

```
ENTER A KEY: <input type="text" ng-model="keyVariable" />
<h1 ng-bind="getMessage(keyVariable)" ng-show="getMessage(keyVariable) != ''"></h1>
```

[**See It Working (Plunker)**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rx2foI83hhCpKppHAgic?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a bunch drew_w! The Plunker link isn't working but I get what you wrote.

Comment: @fauverism Seems like plunker goes down every so often. Should be back up soon!