# Angular ng-message always shows

Tags: angularjs, forms, laravel-5

What reason? Why ng-message always show?
angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js included.There are no errors in the console.

```
        <body>
            <form name="myForm">
                <label>
                    Enter your name:
                    <input type="text"
                           name="myName"
                           ng-model="name"
                           ng-minlength="5"
                           ng-maxlength="20"
                           required />
                </label>
            <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
            (function () {
                      myForm.myName.$error = {
            }})
        </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the `ngMessages` module in your project as a dependecy? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

Comment: `ngMessage` is from angularjs v1.3 and you are using v1.2.7

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869421/use-ngmessages-with-angular-1-2